# Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ continuous. If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded, then $f(A)$ too?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ continuous. If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded, then $f(A)$ too? I think that yes, but I need help with the proof. Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is bounded, then its closure $\bar{A}$ is compact, so $f(\bar{A})$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Assume not. Then for every $k$ there is $x_k \in A$ with $\lvert f(x_k) \rvert > k$. Now $A$ is bounded and $x_k$ is a sequence in $A$. There is a subsequence which is convergent. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** for $n=1$.

If $A $ is bounded then

$$\exists a, b\in \mathbb R\;\;:$$

$A\subset [a,b]$ which is compact

$f(A)\subset f([a,b])$ which is bounded

since $f$ is continuous at $[a,b]$.

Comment: You idea is fine, but you should prove it in general for $\mathbb R^n$, not only $n=1$.